# Is there any stochastic method to  approximate the likelihood?

Tags: stochastic-processes, likelihood

I am looking for a list of stochastic algorithms to approximate likelihoods.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: If likelihood analytically very expensive or not able to calculate then the likelihood-free  (approximate Bayesian computation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) ) methods are available. I am looking for an alternative to such algorithm in domain of stochastic algorithms.

Comment: What do you mean by "stochastic algorithms"? ABC is a stochastic algorithm since it relies on simulation.

Comment: You could try [Googling 'simulated maximum likelihood'](http://www.google.com/search?q=simulated+maximum+likelihood). I don't know anything about it myself beyond the name.

Comment: @Xi'an, I am looking for alternative algorithms, like ABC. Maybe some gradient-free simulation-based algorithms that works as an alternative to ABC. I heard about 'indirect inference' approach, but I am not sure what is it exactly.

Comment: Indirect inference and ABC are very similar (see for instance the incoming <a href="http://www.rss.org.uk/uploadedfiles/userfiles/files/Fearnhead_Dec__14.pdf">Read Paper in JRSS B</a>). They both use simulation. So I am still unclear as to what you are precisely looking for. A way to maximise the likelihood rather than approximating the whole function? This would be the domain of simulated annealing methods.

Comment: I am looking for a list of simulation-based methods that approximate the whole function. It would be great if there is any reviews on this topic?

Comment: @biostat: approximating each value using simulation would be extremely computationally expensive. Moreover, I don't see how you would be able to specify the likelihood, but not compute it directly. Are you doing something non-parametric?